# Formulário dinâmico travando select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, chosen-jquery-plugin

Tenho um formulário dinâmico ([esse](http://jsfiddle.net/3Lzcn7dc/)) com dois campos (um SELECT e um input de quantidade), porém todas as vezes que eu adiciono mais dois campos o SELECT fica travado.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var itemCont = 1;
$("#novoProd").click(function(){
  var novoItem = $("#item").clone();
  // modifica o id do item recem criado
  $(novoItem).attr("id","item"+itemCont);
  var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[1];
  $(novoSelect).attr("id","produtoId"+itemCont);
  $(novoSelect).attr("name","produtoId[]"+itemCont);

  var novoSelect = $(novoItem).children()[3];
  $(novoSelect).attr("id","quant"+itemCont);
  $(novoSelect).attr("name","quant[]"+itemCont);

  $("#formulario").append(novoItem);
  itemCont++;
  $("#itemCont").val(itemCont);
});
```

Estou usando o plugin [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) para criar o campo de pesquisa no SELECT, sem ele o formulário funciona normal.

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose a Country..." class="chosen-select"  id="produtoId" name="produtoId[]">
```

Comment: Como assim "fica travado"?

Comment: Verifique se existe algum erro na consola.

Comment: @dvd, as opções do SELECT não aparecem.

Comment: @PauloRamos, não aponta nenhum erro.